# Error in connecting to Smartsheet using Java API

Tags: java, ssl, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

I am trying to connect to the smartsheet api using the java sdk they have provided. I am only a beginner in java and programming and completely new to smartsheet.

Here is my code (taken from http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#generating-access-token)

```
import com.smartsheet.api.*;
import com.smartsheet.api.models.*;
import com.smartsheet.api.models.enums.SourceInclusion;
import com.smartsheet.api.models.enums.ColumnType;
import com.smartsheet.api.oauth.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SmartsheetException {
        SampleCode();
    }

    public static void SampleCode() throws SmartsheetException {
        // Set the Access Token
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setAccessToken("MY TOKEN");

        // Use the Smartsheet Builder to create a Smartsheet
        Smartsheet smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().setAccessToken(
                token.getAccessToken()).build();

        // Get current user.
        smartsheet.userResources().getCurrentUser();
    }

}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.smartsheet.api.internal.http.HttpClientException: Error occurred.
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.http.DefaultHttpClient.request(DefaultHttpClient.java:169)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.AbstractResources.getResource(AbstractResources.java:192)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.UserResourcesImpl.getCurrentUser(UserResourcesImpl.java:179)
    at com.target.test.Test.SampleCode(Test.java:25)
    at com.target.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.http.DefaultHttpClient.request(DefaultHttpClient.java:149)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1488)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error pretty much tells you about what is going wrong

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The certificate chain returned by the server is not valid. This may happen due to variety of reasons, most likely due to a self-signed/expired/invalid certificate.

You can check the certificates returned from the server using following linux command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourserverUrl:port
```

The problem most likely resides on the server side but for testing purposes you can workaround certificate validation error by adding the certs into your keystore as trused certs. Here is the command to add the cert to keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file intermediate.crt -alias intermediateCA -keystore  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

As part of this import you will be asked to trust the cert, a message like this:

```
Trust this certificate?
```

Just enter yes and you should be good.

Comment: What do I need to do to make it valid? Is it a problem from the server's side?

Comment: Yes, I am checking it out.

Comment: So do I need to add the certificates to a file called intermediate.crt?

Comment: @ak31 name of the file does not matter

Comment: Your solution worked just fine. Now I am getting the following error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:955)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
 at com.smartsheet.api.internal.http.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:64)
 at com.smartsheet.api.SmartsheetBuilder.build(SmartsheetBuilder.java:203)`

Comment: From what I understand, this error also have something to do with certification. 
I went through the source file and found out that the error is happening at this line.
`@Deprecated
    public static final X509HostnameVerifier ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
        = AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;`

which is the line number 144. But I have no idea what to make of it.